# Comparing a list of messages with a list inside an object

Tags: unit-testing, groovy

```
int i = 0
for ( expectedErrors in errors ) {
    final List<String> actualErrors = new ArrayList<>()
    actualRequestMessages?.get(i++)?.errorData?.errors?.each {
        item -> actualErrors.add("${item.message}")
    }
    assert [ ] == ((actualErrors - expectedErrors) + (expectedErrors - actualErrors)), [expectedErrors, actualErrors, "Expected Errors doesn't match actual"]
}
```

Currently, I am comparing actual error messages inside `actualRequestMessages.errorData.errors` with a list of `expectedErrors` as mentioned above. Is there a better way of doing it in Groovy?

Errors come from spock test in the form of a list of errors:

```
errors
[[error1],[error1,error2,error3]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

> ```
> final List<String> actualErrors = new ArrayList<>()
> ```

I believe you can write simply:

```
final actualErrors = []
```

I don't really understand the point of this:

> ```
> assert [ ] == ((actualErrors - expectedErrors) + (expectedErrors - actualErrors))
> ```

The only way this will be true is if this is true:

```
assert actualErrors == expectedErrors
```

Which is a lot simpler.

Btw, this is not idiomatic in Groovy:

> ```
> assert [ ] == something
> ```

This is the idiomatic way:

```
assert !something
```

(because [non-empty collections are *true*](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Truth))